# TLS/SSL Configuration Vulnerability Issue in Salesforce App exchange Security Review

Tags: apex

I got the following issue while Salesforce App exchange App review:

**Issue Description**
Due to historic export restrictions of high grade cryptography, legacy and new web servers are often able and configured to handle weak cryptographic options.

Even if high grade ciphers are normally used and installed, some server misconfiguration could be used to force the use of a weaker cipher to gain access to the supposed secure communication channel.

Ciphers such as SSLv2/SSLv3/TLSv1.0 should not be supported by the server, or Ciphers that utilize a NULL cipher or have weak key lengths. TLS 1.0 has been declared end of life by most systems, and should no longer be used.

More info at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SSL-TLS_(OWASP-CM-001)

It pointed out this code where I was storing URL in a variable:
String endpoint = 'https://*******/**/**/search?limit=30&'+query;

I have used '*' just to hide the URL since it is confidential. Please consider it as a valid URL.

Can someone please help me with this one?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue during security review.

In my case, I included a hyperlink to our website. Our website uses encryption (starts with `https://...`) but the server that hosts the web site accepts TLS version 1.2 and lower.

1. To resolve this, if you have access to the server of the URL you are using, you could try disabling TLS support for version 1.2 and below (as well as SSLv2/SSLv3/TLSv1.0 if they are enabled).
2. A workaround would be to remove the hyperlink if possible
3. If you do not have access to the server, you could try reaching out to the server admin or you could re-submit your security review and include a document under Documents > `False Positives Documentation` that explains why this issue will not pose a security threat in your application (you may need to follow up via office hours to make sure this goes through if they do not approve it).

Hope that helps!